# Azure Container Apps and Windows containers

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

I have a ASP.NET MVC .NET Framework 4.8 project and I want to containerize and deploy to Azure. It will have to be a Windows container (not Linux) because of the framework.

Is that possible to deploy a Windows OS container to Azure Container Apps? Or is this Azure service only for Linux-OS containers?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Container Apps supports Any Linux-based x86-64 (linux/amd64) container image Containers from any public or private container registry

And Windows containers are not currently not supported on container apps.